# how mod x hashing function uses only lower bits of key?

Tags: hash

Assume there are a hash table sized 16, and hash function `h(k) = k % 16.`

It is said that the above hash function is not a good option.

There might be many reasons, but there are 2 major problems respresentatively.

Firstly, if the input keys are even numbers then only 50% of the hash table can be used.

Secondly, the above hash function uses only the last 4 bits of the key.

But I cannot understand the second problem.

How can we know that the only lower 4bits of key is used?

Appreciate for your help in advance.